# Can you select the operator in an if statement from a cell in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Pretty simple, but my searching is revealing nothing. Have a sheet full of KPI's with a cell next to them indicating if higher is better (with >=) or lower is better (with <=).

Is there a way to just compare the score with target using this cell, I'm hoping for something like:
=if(a1&b1&c1,"good","Bad")
where a1 is the score, b1 is the operator and c1 is the target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=IF(COUNTIF(A1,B1&C1),"Good","Bad")`

Regards